# Converting XML to JSON results in unknown characters when running on Centos instead of Windows

Tags: java, linux, servlets, unicode, character-encoding

I have a Java servlet which gets RSS feeds converts them to JSON. It works great on Windows, but it fails on Centos.

The RSS feed contains Arabic and it shows unintelligible characters on Centos. I am using those lines to encode the RSS feed:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = Xml.getBytes("Cp1256");
//  byte[] defaultBytes = Xml.getBytes();

String roundTrip = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8");
```

I tried it on Glassfish and Tomcat. Both have the same problem; it works on Windows, but fails on Centos. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: `byte[] utf8Bytes = Xml.getBytes("Cp1256");` - that makes no sense...

Answer (score 5):

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = Xml.getBytes("Cp1256");
String roundTrip = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8");
```

This is an attempt to correct a badly-decoded string. At some point prior to this operation you have read in `Xml` using the default encoding, which on your Windows box is code page 1256 (Windows Arabic). Here you are encoding that string back to code page 1256 to retrieve its original bytes, then decoding it properly as the encoding you actually wanted, UTF-8.

On your Linux server, it fails, because the default encoding is something other than `Cp1256`; it would also fail on any Windows server not installed in an Arabic locale.

The commented-out line that uses the default encoding instead of explicitly `Cp1256` is more likely to work on a Linux server. However, the real fix is to find where `Xml` is being read, and fix that operation to use the correct encoding(*) instead of the default. Allowing the default encoding to be used is almost always a mistake, as it makes applications dependent on configuration that varies between servers.

(*: for this feed, that's UTF-8, which is the most common encoding, but it may differ for others. Finding out the right encoding for a feed depends on the `Content-Type` header returned for the resource and the `<?xml encoding` declaration. By far the best way to cope with this is to fetch and parse the resource using a proper XML library that knows about this, for example with [`DocumentBuilder.parse(uri)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29).)

Answer (score 1):

There are many places where wrong encoding can be used. Here is the complete list http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8